# i want to change the edittext value in vice versa

Tags: android

I want to change the edittext value in vice versa when I  click in first textbox then second one textchange listener can't work and when I will click on second one the first one textchange listener can't work.

```
editTextPer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    etTextper=new EditTextPerWatcher();
                    editTextHb.removeTextChangedListener(etTexthb);
                    editTextPer.addTextChangedListener(etTextper);
                }
            });

            editTextHb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    etTextper=new EditTextPerWatcher();
                    editTextPer.removeTextChangedListener(etTextper);
                    editTextHb.addTextChangedListener(etTexthb);
                }
            });editTextPer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    etTextper=new EditTextPerWatcher();
                    editTextHb.removeTextChangedListener(etTexthb);
                    editTextPer.addTextChangedListener(etTextper);
                }
            });

            editTextHb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    etTextper=new EditTextPerWatcher();
                    editTextPer.removeTextChangedListener(etTextper);
                    editTextHb.addTextChangedListener(etTexthb);
                }
            });

> BlockquoteeditTextPer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    etTextper=new EditTextPerWatcher();
                    editTextHb.removeTextChangedListener(etTexthb);
                    editTextPer.addTextChangedListener(etTextper);
                }
            });

            editTextHb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    etTextper=new EditTextPerWatcher();
                    editTextPer.removeTextChangedListener(etTextper);
                    editTextHb.addTextChangedListener(etTexthb);
                }
            });


editTextPer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    etTextper=new EditTextPerWatcher();
                    editTextHb.removeTextChangedListener(etTexthb);
                    editTextPer.addTextChangedListener(etTextper);
                }
            });

            editTextHb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    etTextper=new EditTextPerWatcher();
                    editTextPer.removeTextChangedListener(etTextper);
                    editTextHb.addTextChangedListener(etTexthb);
                }
            });


editTextPer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    etTextper=new EditTextPerWatcher();
                    editTextHb.removeTextChangedListener(etTexthb);
                    editTextPer.addTextChangedListener(etTextper);
                }
            });

            editTextHb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    etTextper=new EditTextPerWatcher();
                    editTextPer.removeTextChangedListener(etTextper);
                    editTextHb.addTextChangedListener(etTexthb);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did I understood you correctly? You wanna reverse a string?

If yes this is really simple, but I just describe the algorithm for you (you can do the code by yourself):

1. get input string + create empty result string
2. do a for loop across the input starting with the last element and finishing with the first element
3. in the loop you add every part of the string / char / element to your result string
4. now you should have your reversed string